# Nested For loop over csv files

Tags: python-3.x, csv, iterator, loops

I have 2 .csv datasets from the same source. I was attempting to check if any of the items from the first dataset are still present in the second.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import json
import click

@click.group()

def cli(*args, **kwargs):
    """Command line tool to compare and generate a report of item that still persists from one report to the next."""
    pass

@click.command(help='Compare the keysets and return a list of keys old keys still active in new keyset.')
@click.option('--inone', '-i', default='keys.csv', help='specify the file of the old keyset')
@click.option('--intwo', '-i2', default='keys2.csv', help='Specify the file of the new keyset')
@click.option('--output', '-o', default='results.json', help='--output, -o,   Sets the name of the output.')
def compare(inone, intwo, output):

    csvfile = open(inone, 'r')
    csvfile2 = open(intwo, 'r')
    jsonfile = open(output, 'w')

    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    comparator = csv.DictReader(csvfile2)
    for line in comparator:
        for row in reader:
            if row == line:
                print('#', end='')
                json.dump(row, jsonfile)
                jsonfile.write('\n')
            print('|', end='')
        print('-', end='')


cli.add_command(compare)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

say each csv files has 20 items in it. it will currently iterate 40 times and end when I was expecting it to iterate 400 times and create a report of items remaining.

Everything but the iteration seems to be working. anyone have thoughts on a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating 40 times sounds just about right - when you iterate through your `DictReader`, you're essentially iterating through the wrapped file lines, and once you're done iterating it doesn't magically reset to the beginning - the iterator is done.

That means that your code will start iterating over the first item in the `comparator` (1), then iterate over all items in the `reader` (20), then get the next line from the `comparator`(1), then it won't have anything left to iterate over in the `reader` so it will go to the next `comparator` line and so on until it loops over the remaining comparator lines (18) - resulting in total of 40 loops.

If you really want to  iterate over all of the lines (and memory is not an issue), you can store them as lists and then you get a new iterator whenever you start a `for..in` loop, so:

```
reader = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
comparator = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile2))
```

Should give you an instant fix. Alternatively, you can reset your `reader` 'steam' after the loop with `csvfile.seek(0)`.

That being said, if you're going to compare lines only, and you expect that not many lines will differ, you can load the first line in csv.reader() to get the 'header' and then forgo the `csv.DictReader` altogether by comparing the lines directly. Then when there is a change you can pop in the line into the `csv.reader()` to get it properly parsed and then just map it to the headers table to get the var names.

That should be significantly faster on large data sets, plus seeking through the file can give you the benefit of never having the need to store in memory more data than the current I/O buffer.

Comment: my actual dataset is 58k lines in one and 580k lines in the other. and I think that I may have just enough memory on my computer to get it done the first way. 
However, my data is only getting bigger, so could you please elaborate on the second way of doing it, I was attempting to do by only loading one line from each file into memory at a time, but couldn't figure it out.
Thanks for the help!